# stooped or kicked in "He laughed and stooped them all into the river."?

Tags: word-usage

In the movie "little mouse who was a princess",
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kv1CFTWdofk.

[image]

at the time of 10 minutes 52 seconds,i saw a sentence

> He laughed and stooped them all into the river.

stoop means "to bend (a part of the body) forward and downward",when i watch the movie ,it seems that mouse princess and its coachmen are all kicked into a river nearby by a man passing by.

Maybe it is better to write it as :

> He laughed and kicked them all into the river.

Comment: After a few minutes of listening to the video, the English is pretty awful - it's peppered with really odd grammatical errors. It's almost as though it was written by a non-native speaker. I don't know who was responsible for writing this, but either "stooped" is a typo, or someone has just used the wrong verb. A possibility is that they meant "scooped".

Comment: @BillyKerr  I strongly suspect the girl/woman/boy who is speaking the words is not a native speaker, but has learned to speak English with an American accent. It also seems to me that this person has mumbled or slurred the word in question. YouTube cartoons are NOT a good source of English for learners.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - or they may have employed Americans for the voice overs, but asked them to read the script exactly as written.  But yes you are right, youtube videos are often very poor quality, and not good for learners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my ears, the spoken dialogue says 'he laughed and **shoot** them all into the river". I guess this may be American rural dialect (in some region) for 'shot' (you can shoot something [somewhere] with your foot). The narrator's girlish voice has a heavy American accent. You should be aware that the captions on YouTube are often computer generated, or hastily created by people, and not always by native speakers. They do not always correctly match what is being spoken. You are correct that 'kicked them all into the river' is correct and appropriate standard English for what happened.

Comment: There's a lot of non-native grammatical errors in the video, which suggests this was written by a non-native English speaker.

Answer (score 1):

To my ear, it sounds like **scooped**, which makes much more sense.

The makers of the video probably took it from the page [A Little Mouse Who Was A Princess](https://www.bedtimeshortstories.com/a-little-mouse-who-was-a-princess):

> Walking through the jungle, they came near a town. There was a river flowing in between. They had to cross the bridge over the river. As they were crossing it, a man came from nowhere in the opposite direction. He saw a bunch of mice coming on his way. He laughed and stooped them all into the river. Veikko was very sad for the mouse. But the man laughed loudly and went away. He looked down into the river but he found nowhere.

This very paragraph contains clues that confirm @BillyKerr's view:

> He saw a bunch of mice coming <s>on</s> his way.
> He laughed and <s>stooped</s> them into the river. Veikko was very sad for the <s>mouse</s> (-> logically 'mice').
> He looked down into the river but he <s>found nowhere</s> (-> found them nowhere).

My best guess is that the original word must have been **scooped** (or possibly **shot**) which was then mistyped/corrupted through translation/appropriation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the grammar and syntax of the piece are so bad in places that it really is of no import whether that one word is stooped or scooped, or anything else for that matter.

I would theorise that the script is written by a non-native, under no supervision. It contains a lot of instances where, even if the grammar is technically fine, the idiom is missing a clue.
For the narration they found American voice-over artists whose job it is to read what's written, not to make suggestions on grammar or syntax.
They did the job, anonymously, took the money & ran, thank you very much. There are no credits, beginning or end. Comments are off - probably to avoid people pointing out how bad it is.

If not already crystal clear from my comments so far - don't use this source to learn English.